# How to get more than 1 result through ajax response with json

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I am making a messaging system i have to fetch messages and here is my codes

my ajax code to fetch results-

```
function fetch_conversation() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'message_function.php',
        data: {
            fetch_conversation:'conversation'
        },
        success: function (response) {
            var r = $.parseJSON(response);
            alert(r.nno);
            alert(r.mmessage_from);
        }
    });
}
```

and here is my php code that fetches data and send it to ajax as response-

```
if(isset($_POST['fetch_conversation'])) {
    $select_message=mysql_query("select no,message_from,sent_time,message_body from    messages where message_to='1'  and sent_time > '2014-12-02 17:43:35' union select   no,message_to,sent_time,message_body from messages where message_from='1' and sent_time >   '2014-12-02 17:43:35' ")or die(mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_message)) {
        $nno= $row['no'];
        echo json_encode($nno);
        $mmessage_from=$row['message_from'];
        echo json_encode($mmessage_from);
    }

    exit();
}
```

The query i used fetches more than 1 row and my problem is that json cannot return values in fetch conversation function and if the query fetches only 1 row it json shows all the values and all the alerts is visible.how to make my fetch conversation function works to get more than 1 row and display the alerts please any help will be appreciated and also please try to give the codes that is cross browser thanks....

Comment: $mmessage_from[] and put the echo outside the wile loop

Comment: i do that but nothing works

Comment: you're not doing it right. Put both echo outside the loop, on assign $nno will become $nno[] and $mmessage_from will become $mmessage_from[] when you're outside the loop (before the exit) you need to print them both with echo json_encode($nno[]); and echo json_encode($mmessage_from[]);

Comment: like @MarcoMura said, or use just a single array like `$out = array("nno" => array(),"message_form" => array())` and only json_encode this after the loop

Comment: ya i do that as you say not alert display

Comment: please consider my jquery code i think there is a problem in that json code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**in the mesage_function.php file**

if(isset($_POST['fetch_conversation'])) {
    $select_message=mysql_query("select no,message_from,sent_time,message_body from    messages where message_to='1'  and sent_time > '2014-12-02 17:43:35' union select   no,message_to,sent_time,message_body from messages where message_from='1' and sent_time >   '2014-12-02 17:43:35' ")or die(mysql_error());
    $array = array();
    $i = 0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_message)) {
        $array[$i]['no']= $row['no'];
        $array[$i]['mmessage_from']=$row['message_from'];
        $i++;
   }
   echo json_encode($array);
}   

**and in the ajax sucess alert only response and check log**

**try this, i hope this help.**
```

use this code in your sucess response..
put this code after parsejson
add your table id is here.

```
#add_your_id_here

function fetch_conversation()
 {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'message_function.php',
        data: {
            fetch_conversation:'conversation'
        },
        success: function (response) {

            var r = JSON.parse(response);
                var text = "";
                var x;
                for (x in r) {
                    $('#add_your_id_here').append('<tr><td>'+r[x]['mmessage_from']+'</td><td>'+r[x]['no']+'</td></tr>');

                }
            }
        });
 }
```

Comment: yes it alerts me all values but how to extract the values like i do in json to extract i put in elments

Comment: can you give me example which output you require..?

Comment: like i want to get all the values in 'no' and values of 'message_from' in ajax function so i can give the innerHTML to my elements

Comment: sorry your code is not working but thanks for your help

Comment: there is no error the code is not displaying any results in my <p> elements which has id message

Comment: can you replace that <p> tag to <table> tag for some minute and check my code again.
also give id to table and don't forgot to replace id which is in my code

Comment: my code is identical to your code inplace of ad-you-id-here there my id id which is a table element and i place the jquery code just after the json code

Comment: I think now this can help for you.. check code again.
check now fetch_conversation() function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get all results when to do:

```
console.log(r);
```

You could try

```
$.each(r, function(k, row) {
    alert(row.nno);
    alert(row.mmessage_from);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
   function fetch_conversation()
   {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'message_function.php',
    data: {
    fetch_conversation:'conversation'
    },
    success: function (response) {

    var msg_no=response['no'];
    var msg_from=response['message_from'];

    alert(msg_no);
    alert(msg_from);
    }
    });
  }
```

and your php

```
if(isset($_POST['fetch_conversation']))
 {
  $select_message=mysql_query("select no,message_from,sent_time,message_body from       messages where message_to='1'  and sent_time > '2014-12-02 17:43:35' union select   no,message_to,sent_time,message_body from messages where message_from='1' and sent_time >   '2014-12-02 17:43:35' ")or die(mysql_error());
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_message))
 {
  $nno[]= $row['no'];

  $mmessage_from[]=$row['message_from'];

  }
  $arr['no']=$nno;
  $arr['message_from']=$mmessage_from;

   echo json_encode($arr);
 exit();
 }
```

Comment: it is giving me undefined value alert

Comment: add `dataType=json,` on ajax then try

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_POST['fetch_conversation']))
 {
    $select_message = mysql_query("SELECT no,message_from,sent_time,message_body 
                                   FROM  messages WHERE message_to='1'  
                                   AND sent_time > '2014-12-02 17:43:35' 
                                   UNION 
                                   SELECT no,message_to,sent_time,message_body 
                                   FROM messages WHERE message_from='1' AND sent_time > '2014-12-02 17:43:35' ") or die(mysql_error());
     // create a result array to send response
     $result = array();   
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select_message))
     {
        $_temp = array();
        $_temp['no'] = $row['no'];
        $_temp['message_from'] = $row['message_from'];
        $result[] = $_temp;
        unset($_temp);
     }
     @header("Content-Type:text/json");
     echo json_encode($result);
     exit;
 }
```

Please try with the above code. This will give you json which is created by the multiple array records.At your html code please do as @Ferret suggested.